# Creating HTML Form Fields Into Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, fputcsv

16-Jun-16

Hi,
I have an HTML form with text, radio buttons, check boxes, and text area fields. I want to write all the fields into a CSV file. It is writing to the CSV file, but unfortunately if there is a comma in any of the fields, it moves the text after the comma to the next field.

I did some research and found I should use 'fputcsv'. All the examples that I found were getting their data from a database, and creating an array. I would like to know how to create an array from the data in my form so I can use it with 'fputcsv'. Below is a sample of my code.

```
// Create file. If file has been created, open file.
$myfile = fopen("ZZZmycsv.csv", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

// Write to file.
// Column headers
$msg = "First Name, Last Name, Organization, Email, City, State, Comment 1, Comment 2 \n";

// Form variables
$msg .= "$firstName, $lastName, $organization, $email, $city, $state, $comment1, $comment2 \n";
```

Please be as detailed as possible with your answers.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: I believe you need to use delimiters! Then you can have commas in your data and it wont break the columns [check the third parameter entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#refsect1-function.fputcsv-parameters)

Comment: "how to create an array..?" `$array=[$firstName,...$comment2];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use fputcsv, there is already a default escape character ("\")
so all you have to do is make an array from the form inputs and write them into the file.

```
// Create file. If file has been created, open file.
$myfile = fopen("ZZZmycsv.csv", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

// Write to file.
// Column headers
$headers = array('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Organization', 'Email', 'City', 'State', 'Comment 1', 'Comment 2');
fputcsv($myfile, $headers);

// Form variables
$formArray = array($firstName, $lastName, $organization, $email, $city, $state, $comment1, $comment2);
fputcsv($myfile, $formArray);
```

In this example i wrote the headers into the file too, but if you're using fopen(..., **"a"**); this will possibly make no sense so you may want to use **"w"** as parameter (not if you want to store more than 1 line in the file. then dont write headers before each line)

hope this helped, cheers

Comment: Cashbee, thanks for the assistance - I will try your suggestion. One question though: in the array, I will have a total of 18 variables. What is the best practice in splitting the 18 variables, instead of having them all on one array line?

Comment: Cashbee, your suggestion worked perfect! As an FYI, I am using Dreamweaver and all the variables wrapped to the next lines. I have one array() with 18 variables over three lines. If there is a better way, please advice. But if it is working, why redesign the wheel, correct?

Is it possible to make the column headers static? My workaround was to upload the CSV file with the headers in their appropriate fields. I deleted the two lines of code you wrote for the headers.

I truly appreciate your assistance!

Comment: I'm glad i could help. i would appreciate if you would upvote my answer too since i am on the hunt for reputation i still am under 50 ;)

how you format your lines in the code does not matter btw ;)

Comment: what do you mean by making the column headers static?

Comment: 21-Jun-16

Hi Cashbee,
I tried to upvote your answer, but I have to have a total of 15 Reputations - I am new to this site.

What I meant about the column headers being static was for the column headers not to be written each time. My solution was I created a spreadsheet with the column headers and I uploaded the spreadsheet to its proper location. Now every time I write to the CSV, the column headers are not being re-written. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks again for your assistance! Truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP: There's a function for that

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Edit: To duplicate the PHP documentation:

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

The above example will write the following to file.csv:

> aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
>   123,456,789
>   """aaa""","""bbb"""